# Custom UIButton does not change its image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I created a custom UIButton, and it has a field "selected" to identify that this button is selected or not. As default: it set its image as image1. When it is selected it changes to image2.

```
@interface MyButton: UIButton

@property (getter=isSelected, setter=setSelected:) BOOL selected;

@end

@implementation MyButton

@synthesize selected = _selected;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.selected = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) setSelected:(BOOL)selected
{
    if (selected)
    {
        [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];        
    }
    else
    {
        [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];        
    }

    _selected = selected;
}

-(BOOL) isSelected
{
    return _selected;
}
```

Now, from a UIViewController, I add this custom buttom to its view. And when the user click another button, I want my custom buttom should change its image (from image1 -> image2 and vice verse).

```
@interface SessionViewController (){    
    MyButton* btn;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    btn = [[MyButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
}

- (IBAction) touchChangeStateButton
{
    BOOL b = btn.isSelected;
    btn.selected = !b; 
}

@end
```

My question is why my custom buttom does not change its image??? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the UIButton's built-in *selected* property is interfering with your custom one. I tried changing the name to 'selacted' (just to make it different) and changed all the corresponding code, as seen below, and it seemed to work as you expect it to.

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton

@property (getter=isSelacted, setter=setSelacted:) BOOL selacted;

@end

@implementation MyButton

@synthesize selacted = _selacted;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.selacted = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) setSelacted:(BOOL)selacted
{
    if (selacted)
    {
        [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    _selacted = selacted;
}

-(BOOL) isSelacted
{
    return _selacted;
}
```

And then in your viewController:

```
- (IBAction) touchChangeStateButton
{
    BOOL b = btn.isSelacted;
    btn.selacted = !b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if (selected)
    {
        [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];        
    }
    else
    {
        [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];        
    }
```

With this:

```
    if (selected)
        {
// set image for selected state
            [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];        
        }
        else
        {
// set image for normal state
            [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];        
        }
```

Or you can simple define both images in one go from your init method

```
[self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: My purpose is to change its image, not to change its states (e.g., UIControlStateSelected, UIControlStateNormal). Your way does not work.

Comment: You are not changing its states, just the backGround images for each state. Changing the image on normal state would not affect the button when in selected state. You then need to define all images in your init method to use with this button. If this is the only  thing you need, you don't even need to create MyButton class just set the images when initializing your button programmatically

Comment: No, actually my case is more complicated. I don't want to write all code here. My custom button contains other sub views, like 2 UILabels, 2 UIImageViews, etc... And in UIViewController, there are many such custom buttons. That's why I must write my generic custom button.